# Как изменить стили у первого элемента при наведении на второй элемент?

Tags: html, css

Необходимо, чтобы при наведение на ссылку "*Интернет магазин Арога*" ссылка "*Интернет магазин Солана*" меняла цвет.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался сделать так:

```css
.sbm_top_link:nth-child(2):hover + .sbm_top_link a {
  color: #222222;
  background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="sbmts_bl">
  <a class="sbm_top_link fancybox" href="#">Интернет магазин Солана </a>
  <a class="sbm_top_link fancybox" href="#">Интернет магазин Арога</a>
</div>
```

Comment: насколько я понимаю, можно только наоборот, при наведении на первый менять следующий. А так - только через js

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Тут уже уйма вариантов - надо бы принять какой-нибудь ответ.

Answer (score 5):

```css
ul {
    margin: 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}

ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 14px;
}

ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #555;    
}

ul:hover > li > a {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

ul > li > a:hover {
    background: #999;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Интернет магазин Солана</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Интернет магазин Арога</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: В чём принципиальное отличие от [этого](/a/521309/178988)?

Answer (score 3):

Я всё-таки исхитрился и сделал вот такое чудо на CSS.
В Хроме работает, в FF и в IE11 - тоже.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  background: antiquewhite;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
}

.a1 { order: 1; }
.a2 { order: 2; }
.a1a, .a2a { position: absolute; }

a:hover { background: aquamarine; }
a:hover ~ a { background: silver; }
.a2:hover ~ .a1 { z-index: 1; }
.a1:hover ~ .a2 { z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="a2 a2a" href="#">Интернет магазин Арога</a>
  <a class="a1 a1a" href="#">Интернет магазин Солана </a>
  <a class="a2 a2b" href="#">Интернет магазин Арога</a>
  <a class="a1 a1b" href="#">Интернет магазин Солана </a>
</div>
```

Comment: +1, `flex` давно научился жонглировать порядком кода, только не кажется ли что такой код поддерживать - мучение? В лисе работает, а `IE` - http://i.stack.imgur.com/by43h.png

Comment: @Other, да, поддерживать это мне бы не хотелось. Я даже пока писал успел запутаться. IE у тебя какой-то старый, судя по тому, что в нём разметка самого SO поехала. В 11м может заработать (хотя надо проверять), а в 10м в любом случае, без добавления ms'ных префиксов (и старого синтаксиса) не заработает.

Comment: @Other, проверил, в IE11 работает.

Comment: `IE8` по дефолту. Я его ни разу не запускал на рабочей оси, это, так сказать, его первый раз. Хм, запуска, конечно.

Comment: @Other, я придумал простой вариант. См. другой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Раз на то пошло, то вот ещё вариант:

```css
#test {
  border: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

#test:hover + a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  
  <input id="test"><a class="solana" href="#">Интернет магазин Солана</a>
  
  <label for="test">
    
    <a class="aroga" href="#">Интернет магазин Арога</a>
    
  </label>
  
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/482y1c53/

---

Но лучше с помощью JS (ну или JQuery, как вам удобней):

```js
(function () {

    var aroga = document.querySelector('.sbmts_bl :nth-child(2)');

    var solanaClassList = aroga.previousElementSibling.classList;

    aroga.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {

        solanaClassList.add('hightlight');

    });

    aroga.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {

        solanaClassList.remove('hightlight');

    });

})();
```

```css
.sbm_top_link:nth-child(2):hover + .sbm_top_link a {
  color: #222222;
  background: #333333;
}

.hightlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sbmts_bl">
  <a class="sbm_top_link fancybox" href="#">Интернет магазин Солана </a>
  <a class="sbm_top_link fancybox" href="#">Интернет магазин Арога</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pco94ys2/

Comment: О! Круто с инпутом. Хотя и невалидно ведь?

Comment: @Qwertiy, c чего вы взяли, что невалидно? [Вот](https://goo.gl/3pYBZ0), проверьте сами — всё валидно.

Comment: Странно. Я ожидал, что вложение активных элементов (label и ссылка) друг в друга невалино.

Answer (score 2):

1. Если не принципиально, то в html меняем ссылки местами.
2. С помощью свойства `direction: rtl;` и табличного отображения, делаем вид, что никто ни с кем местами и не менялся.
3. Применяем нужный селектор и получаем необходимый результат.

```css
.sbmts_bl {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.sbmts-bl__wrapper {
  border: 3px solid green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  display: table;
  direction: rtl;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.sbm_top_link {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.sbm_top_link:nth-child(1):hover + .sbm_top_link {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="sbmts_bl">
  <div class="sbmts-bl__wrapper">
    <a class="sbm_top_link fancybox" href="#">Интернет магазин Арога</a>
    <a class="sbm_top_link fancybox" href="#">Интернет магазин Солана </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Наконец-то дошло, что отступов между ссылками нет. В таком случае всё элементарно.

```css
nav {
  background: #777;
  padding: 0 3em;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: antiquewhite;
  padding: .5em;
}

div:hover a:hover {
  background: aquamarine;
}

div:hover a {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      Интернет магазин Солана
    </a><a href="#">
      Интернет магазин Арога
    </a><a href="#">
      И ещё один
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

И даже ещё проще (хотя подойдёт только для фона и цвета текста):

```css
nav {
  background: #777;
  padding: 0 3em;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: antiquewhite;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em;
}

div:hover {
  background: silver;
}

a:hover {
  background: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      Интернет магазин Солана
    </a><a href="#">
      Интернет магазин Арога
    </a><a href="#">
      И ещё один
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Интересно, но возможно нужно подсветить именно одну, особую, ссылку? Подсвечивать всё разом и одну выделять я ещё первым хотел ответить, но возник этот вопрос, который спрашивать лень запретила.

Comment: @Other, на одну есть ответ про `ltr`.

Answer (score 1):

[Мануал](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/adjacent)

```
E + F { Описание правил стиля }
```

> Для управления стилем соседних элементов используется символ плюса
>   (+), который устанавливается между двумя селекторами E и F. Пробелы
>   вокруг плюса не обязательны. Стиль при такой записи применяется к
>   элементу F, но только в том случае, **если он является соседним** для
>   элемента E и **следует сразу после него**.

Сделать через css без костылей не получится, Вам необходимо воспользоваться js/jquery.

**UPD** - *пример кода на jquery*

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sbm_top_link:nth-child(2)").hover(
    function() {
      $(".sbm_top_link:nth-child(1)").addClass('test');
    },
    function() {
      $(".sbm_top_link:nth-child(1)").removeClass('test');
    }
  )
});
```

```css
.test {
  color: #222222;
  background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sbmts_bl">
  <a class="sbm_top_link fancybox" href="#">Интернет магазин Солана </a>&nbsp;
  <a class="sbm_top_link fancybox" href="#">Интернет магазин Арога</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один вариант, основанный на дублировании ссылок. Но на этот раз простой. Работает с любым числом ссылок, причём css от этого не зависит.

IE11+ и все остальные браузеры. В более ранних остальные ссылки не будут менять фон.

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: antiquewhite;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 0;
}

a:hover {
  background: aquamarine;
  z-index: 1;
}

a:hover ~ div a {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Интернет магазин Солана</a>
  <a href="#">Интернет магазин Арога</a>
  <a href="#">Ещё какой-то интернет-магазин</a>
  <a href="#">И ещё один</a>
  <a href="#">Да много их</a>
  <a href="#">Очень много</a>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Интернет магазин Солана</a>
    <a href="#">Интернет магазин Арога</a>
    <a href="#">Ещё какой-то интернет-магазин</a>
    <a href="#">И ещё один</a>
    <a href="#">Да много их</a>
    <a href="#">Очень много</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Вот это уже можно назвать нормальным кодом. Хотя лично на мой вкус - это слегка... эпатажный код; выделять пункт при наведении - зачем остальные трогать? Разве что эпилептикам радость моргания всех ссылок подарить.

Comment: @Other, у него-то табы без отступов... Блин.. Пока писал это, дошло, что в том случае всё вообще элементарно решается. Сейчас ещё ответ напишу... А вообще, я хотел сказать, что там мерцания не будет.

Comment: @Other, готово. Это ж надо было решать проблему, которой нет. Я про то, что перекрашивание не должно срабатывать при наведении между ссылками.

Answer (score 0):

Интересная модификация соседнего ответа для случая, когда между ссылками всё-таки нужен зазор. Суть в том, что `div:hover` должен срабатывать только тогда, когда на одного из его потомков навели мышку, но не срабатывать, когда навели на него самого. Очевидно, что `pointer-events` для этого не подходит. А вот `display: contents` отлично работает. Ну и для старых браузеров можно добавить в качестве фоллбэка `display: inline-block` и там подсветка будет работать чуть хуже.

```css
nav {
  background: #777;
  padding: 0 3em;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  display: contents;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: antiquewhite;
  padding: .5em;
}

a + a {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

div:hover a:hover {
  background: aquamarine;
}

div:hover a {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      Интернет магазин Солана
    </a><a href="#">
      Интернет магазин Арога
    </a><a href="#">
      И ещё один
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```