# Поменять стиль элемента при наведении на другой элемент

Tags: html, css

Нужно при наведении на `three` поменять стиль `six` (средствами CSS)

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.three {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.six {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="four">
  <div class="five">
    <div class="six">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Гуглил и ничего толкового не нашел

Comment: Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/293281/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) было похожее обсуждение. Решили путем javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее так нельзя.

Но можно немного исхитриться. В хроме работает, в остальных не проверял.

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.one, .four {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

.three {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.six {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.one {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.three {
  pointer-events: all;
}

.one:hover ~ .four .six {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="four">
  <div class="five">
    <div class="six">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проверил, в ФФ и Edge - тоже работает. Благодарю! Можете пояснить как, в данном случае, работает `pointer-events: all`?

Comment: @Дмытрык, снова разрешает элементу реагировать на мышку.

Comment: кстати ..тут вопрос назрел ..а при наведении на жёлтый сменить синий , как ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, прикрыть его сверху прозрачным блоком, который в разметке будет раньше синего, но во флексе за счёт order встанет в нужное место))

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, а ещё вот так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521309/178988.

Comment: @Qwertiy  спасибо ..

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, мог бы и "лайкнуть" ответ

Comment: @Дмытрык сорри ..запарился

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, а ещё вот такое есть - как раз с подменой и наложением: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521289/178988

Comment: @Дмытрык, если полазить по моим css'ным ответам, там много всяких финтов найти можно))

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, о, похоже все 3 варианта с подсветкой в том вопросе. Из интересного у меня ещё :focus где-то был, когда я baseline смещал.

Answer (score 3):

Чистым CSS такое не сделать, только если элементы на одном уровне

[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```css
body{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.three{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.six{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.one:hover + .four .six{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="four">
    <div class="five">
      <div class="six">
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

При помощи jQuery будет так ([ассоциация](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910049/on-a-css-hover-event-can-i-change-another-divs-styling)):

```
$(function() {
  $('.three').hover(function() {
    $('.six').css('background-color', 'blue');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $('.six').css('background-color', 'yellow');
  });
});
```

Comment: Ну можно чуть допилить)