# Как сделать с помощью CSS, чтобы при наведении на ссылку в одном диве выделялась ссылка в другом диве?

Tags: css

Вот такая разметка:

```
<div id="wrap1">
    <a href="#" class="a">AAAA</a>
</div>
<div id="wrap2">
    <a href="#" class ="b">BBBB</a>
</div>
```

При наведении мышью на элемент .a необходимо, к примеру, закрасить черным элемент .b

Comment: Без скриптов - никак.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/521273/178988